# Prevent iAd from shifting other views

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, iad

I have an iAd banner in my application however, sometimes (usually when the iAd has an error) it will shift my other views up. Is it possible to just have the banner view overlap my other views instead of interfere with them?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    Banner.hidden = true
    Banner.delegate = self
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
}


func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    NSLog("Error")
    Banner.hidden = true
}

func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    Banner.hidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear if you are manually adding the iAD banner from a *singleton* or just using the built in *shortcut* `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`. 
If you mix the two together you might have strange results.

Try removing `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` and manually add the banner view to your view hierarchy.

[this](https://github.com/perlfly/iAdExample) small example might help.

When you opt for the *shortcut* solution `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`, your view hierarchy will be embedded in a bigger view containing the banner and automatically animating as you described. In this case you do not need to conform and implement the delegate methods.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick! Thank you! I was mixing the two together